# Drive strength definition & fanout

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, logic-gates, delay, gate-driving

Given an inverter of drive strength N (example N=16) and input capacitance 1.6fF, does it mean that it can drive

1. N times its gate capacitance, i.e. 16*1.6f=25.6 fF, or
2. N times the unit capacitance, i.e.: Cu=1.6f/16*16 = 1.6fF (essentially again its own gate capacitance).

In terms of CMOS standard libraries, is fanout the same as drive strength?

I would say yes; according to Wikipedia FO=Cload/Cin where the gate under consideration is driven by a gate N (=16x) smaller and drives a gate N (=16x) times larger. In my example, I know that the x16 inverter has Cin=1.6fF. So an x256 inverter should have Cin=16*1.6=25.6fF and hence FO=16 (same as drive strength).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnP9Ec.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, when a standard cell library lists the drive strengths (in terms of x5, x8, x16 etc), does it mean relative to the gates of the same type or relative to an inverter or relative to a unit inverter?

Comment: Drive strength typically stands for current. (Dis)charging the input capacitance will taker longer with lower drive strength; are there any timing specifications?

Comment: Not (yet), my question is mainly about understanding. My standard library provides different "xN" (x5, x8, x15, x31, ...) for various blocks; all that's in the DS is pin input caps and propagation delays. I assume there must be a standard "meaning" of "the inverter is x16".

Comment: I've searched for the difference between fanout and drive strength and your answer sounds correct. One thing I found out is that fanout mainly is used in Verilog/RTL level while drive strength is mainly used in physical design or SPICE level. Not sure if this is the major difference. Depends on context, they might be slightly different.